# Performance Dashboards empty in SCOM 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, .net, scom

Every dashboard was running fine, but after server restarted it's empty

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDOsg.png

I tried to delete and make it again and tried other options not only this "processor utilization" everything is empty just like this (Only Performance widgets tho, details, state and so on are OK). It doesn't show any alerts on any of the menaged agents, all healthy and good.

What could be the problem?

Comment: few minutes after i posted this got an error that SCOM stopped working, closed it - openend again and the dashboards work now, weird.... still, why was this happening?

Answer (score 0):

my friend.

It sounds like a console issue. These widgets use standard OS performance collection rules so you need to check if you can see performance data using standard performance view (not dashboard). If so - it's definitely console issue. Do you have SCOM 2012 SP1 or SCOM 2012 R2 SP1 CU3?

Thank you,
Roman.